# Replication Issues for client machines connecting to Master in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have done replication set up between 2 database in mysql
One is master and second is slave.
Now whenever I do any change on master database on same machine it works fine and data is getting replicated to slave .

Now when I connect to master database from different machine using tools like Toad , workbench and perform any action (insert , update  etc) this is not getting replicated to slave .

Does mysql support replication  this scenario.

IF yes please share the steps ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change data through gui tool todd etc in below manner-

first select database by use for an example-

```
use mydb;
update mytable set mycol='value' where mycol2='value';
```

Now check if data is replicating..

Also execute below command on slave and provide results if not replicating-

```
show slave status;
```

Comment: When i change directly on master database , it is working . But when i use any tool wheather its toad , mysql work bench its not working.

Comment: have you checked in a way i have suggested in my post, please check and if still not getting on slave then provide results of show slave status;